# Getting error while running rake task in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task, whenever

When I run

```
$bundle env
```

got the result as:

```
Bundler 1.5.2
Ruby 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygems 2.2.1
rvm 1.25.15 (stable)
GEM_HOME /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
GEM_PATH /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
```

but while running whenever and in console  running the 
`tail -f log/cron_log.log` I got the following issue

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

```
$crontab -l
```

35 0 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get update

35 1 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get -y upgrade

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: trrm
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

* * * * * /bin/bash -i -c 'cd /var/www/trrm && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ad_has_expired_task --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -i -c 'cd /var/www/trrm && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ad_going_to_expire_task --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: trrm
```

Comment: Which command gives the error?

Comment: running the tail -f log/cron_log.log

Comment: `tail` just open log file! I think you start rake tasks through cron and exactly this task raises exceptions. Show what do you have in cron tasks (`crontab -l` in console)

Comment: @gotva:  Please see the Edit section for crontab -l

Comment: I think if you can run in console `cd /var/www/trrm && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ad_has_expired_task` (or simple variant `rake -T` instead of real task) then the problem in bash script and exactly with `bash -i -c`. PS I am not close friend with bash